# Getting return value from action with jquery.forms.js options...MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Im including the popular file jquery.form.js. I have the following:

```
 var options = {
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
    success: afterSubmit  // post-submit callback 
  };

 $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
     $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
     return false;
  });


 function afterSubmit(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
   // i want to check for an error
}
```

I call this action:

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public string UploadDocument(DocumentModel model)
    {
        if (noerror)
        return "ok";
        else
         return "the error";
    }
```

Somewhere in the parameters 'responseText, statusText, xhr, $form' the return string is stored.

Where is my return string stored, or how do i store it, so i can check the results when the 'afterSubmit' javascript function is called? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never return strings from controller actions. In ASP.NET MVC controller actions should return ActionResults:

```
[HttpPost] 
public string UploadDocument(DocumentModel model)
{
    if (noerror)
        return Content("ok");
    else
        return Content("the error");
}
```

and then the result will be stored in the `responseText` variable.

Obviously testing in your javascript `if (responseText == 'ok')` seems like something absolutely horrible and for this reason there's JSON:

```
[HttpPost] 
public string UploadDocument(DocumentModel model)
{
    if (noerror)
        return Json(new { success = true });
    else
        return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

so that in your javascript you could work directly with the underlying types (boolean in this case):

```
function afterSubmit(response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    if (response.success) {
        alert('super! we succeeded');
    } else {
        alert('Oh snap!');
    }
}
```