# Get Action class result (return) String in JQuery ajax success

Tags: jsp, jquery

In my JSP page, I have a form and some divs

```
<form id="personDetail" name="personDetail" action="personDetail">
<!-- input fields -->
</form>
<div id="sucess"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="edit"></div>
<div id="input"></div>
```

I am using ajax call to submit the form.

In my action class I have the following code

**ActionClas**

```
if(condition1)
{
//processing statements
return "success";
}
else if(condition2)
{
//processing statements
return "error";
}
else if(condition3)
{
//processing statements
return "input";
}
else if(condition4)
{
//processing statements
return "edit";
}
```

Ajax call

```
$(document).on('click', ".saveButton", function(){
        var formId='personDetail';
        var form = $("#"+formId);
        form.submit(function ()
        {
                var urlAction=form.attr('action');
                var dataFields=form.serialize();
                $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: urlAction,
            data: dataFields,
            success: function (data) {
                    var ajaxResult= $('<div/>').html(data),
                    $ajaxContent = ajaxResult.find('#ajaxContent');
                var ajaxActionResult=$('<div/>').html($ajaxContent);
                $("#success").html(ajaxActionResult);
            }
        });
         return false;
    });
});
```

In struts.xml, I have mentioned some JSPs for each result and it is returning in Ajax.

All are returning to success and getting as HTML content. That I am setting to **DIV** with **id="success"**. So all results are setting to that DIV.

I want to display each result in appropriate div. That is, if action class return string is **error**, I want to set the result to Div with **id="error"**, if it's **input**, then result should set to DIV with **id="input"**, similar for other one also.

As all the results are returning to success in Ajax, there is no point in using **Error** in ajax also. And also it is not possible for edit and input.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this : [Getting return value from action with jquery.forms.js options...MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036796/getting-return-value-from-action-with-jquery-forms-js-options-mvc3/11036860#11036860)

PS: Just change your action class to return Json string.. and use that particular key in your "afterSubmit" function(response.YOUR_KEY == "YOUR_TEST_VALUE") to get desired output.